# Provide an else condition for every else if condition in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My client offers online ordering on his site but every day he has different delivery times. He uses a third a party solution on an external site to handle the online orders and we don't want to transfer the user to that site unless online ordering is available.  So I built a crude modal alert box that when clicked will show the user a message that online ordering is available with a link to the external site.  The code uses `new Date().getDay();` to determine the current day and then a series of `if & else if` statements to show the correct modal. This all works, but since we have different different delivery hours, I need to show an `else` condition with a different message for each `if` statement showing a modal with the delivery times for the next day.

Like I said, this is kind of crude and can more than likely be refactored to many less lines of code. But if I can add an else condition for every if, than this is all I really need at this point.  Thank you.

**If / Else If Statements**

```
var monStartTime = '4:00 PM';
var monEndTime = '8:00 PM';

var teuStartTime = '11:00 AM';
var teuEndTime = '9:00 PM';

var wedStartTime = '11:00 AM';
var wedEndTime = '9:00 PM';

... 

var curr_day = new Date().getDay();
var curr_time = getval();

if (curr_day == '1' && get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(monStartTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(monEndTime)) {
    document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
        $.sweetModal({
            content: '<h2>Online Ordering is Available!</h2>' +
                'Please click the button below to begin your online order.' +
                '<div class="sweet-modal-buttons"><a href="http://pizzospizzeria.hungerrush.com" target="_blank" class="button greenB">Start Order</a></div>',
            // icon: $.sweetModal.ICON_SUCCESS
        });
    };
} else if (curr_day == '2' && get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(teuStartTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(teuEndTime)) {
    document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
        $.sweetModal({
            content: '<h2>Online Ordering is Available!</h2>' +
                'Please click the button below to begin your online order.' +
                '<div class="sweet-modal-buttons"><a href="http://pizzospizzeria.hungerrush.com" target="_blank" class="button greenB">Start Order</a></div>',
            // icon: $.sweetModal.ICON_SUCCESS
        });
    };
} else if ...
```

**I need to squeeze one of these Else statements into every Else If**

```
...

} else {
    document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
        $.sweetModal({
            content: '<h2>Online Ordering is Not Available</h2>' +
                'Online ordering will be available again tomorrow from 11:00am to 9:00pm',
            // icon: $.sweetModal.ICON_ERROR,
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Close',
                classes: 'redB'
            }]
        });
    };
}
...
```

Comment: Squeeze in else { newFunction() } to avoid repeating the same issue in the future

you can use notepad++ regex replace.

Comment: Wrap your things in an array or objects and then access them very easely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeating the same thing in every code block. If you find yourself re-using something, then make it a function.

```
//Store our button event as a function instead of repeating it
function setupOrderAvailable() {
    document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
        $.sweetModal({
            content: '<h2>Online Ordering is Available!</h2>' +
                'Please click the button below to begin your online order.' +
                '<div class="sweet-modal-buttons"><a href="http://pizzospizzeria.hungerrush.com" target="_blank" class="button greenB">Start Order</a></div>',
            // icon: $.sweetModal.ICON_SUCCESS
        });
    };
}

function setupOrderNotAvailable() {
    document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
        $.sweetModal({
            content: '<h2>Online Ordering is Not Available</h2>' +
            'Online ordering will be available again tomorrow from 11:00am to 9:00pm',
            // icon: $.sweetModal.ICON_ERROR,
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Close',
                classes: 'redB'
            }]
        });
    }
};

//Store a flag to let us know if ordering is available or not
var orderingIsAvailable = false;

//Monday
if (curr_day == '1' && get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(monStartTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(monEndTime)) {
   orderingIsAvailable = true;

//Tuesday
} else if (curr_day == '2' && get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(teuStartTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(teuEndTime)) {
   orderingIsAvailable = true;

//Wednesday
} else if ...


//Call a function to setup our button depending on ordering availability
if (orderingIsAvailable) {
    setupOrderAvailable();
} else {
    setupOrderNotAvailable();
}
```

I didn't go the full distance here. Your method of determining whether ordering is available can be much better, but this is at least a push in the right direction, and should allow you to add the alert you're looking for.

Comment: Man, my OCD thanks you!! I knew the code looked repetitive and messy, but still having my jQuery training wheels on, I wasn't quite sure how to tackle it.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Definitely take a good look at Ibrahim's answer as well, his object method is a much simpler way to check if ordering is available. Store all the rules in one place, and then your `if` can just say "Go check today's rules", as Ibrahim does in his example.

Answer (score 3):

```
var days = {
    // sunday
    '1': { startTime: '4:00 PM', endTime: '4:00 PM' },
    // monday
    '2': { /* ... */ },
    // ...
};

var curr_day = new Date().getDay();
var curr_time = getval();

var day = days[curr_day]; // get the current day object from the days object

if(day) {                 // if day is supported
    // check if day.startTime < curr_time < day.endTime
    if(get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(day.startTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(day.endTime)) {
        document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
            // online ordering available blah blah
        };
    }
    else { // THE ELSE YOU WANT TO SQUEEZE IN
        document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
            // comeback tomorrow blah blah
        };
    }
}
else {
    // this day is not supported blah blah
}
```

Comment: This is great; I can now refractor my days code along with the solution from @santi.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Separating those logics into function like santi did is even betterr!